# How to search for a string of text in a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am filtering search results for a worksheet with easy to use command buttons and I am trying to hide all rows that do not contain the text provided in a cell.

I have then code to hide all rows that contain an exact input in a cell but I am trying to include partials as well.

```
For a = 2 To 200
    If Worksheets("Purchase Log").Cells(a, 2 Or 6).Value = Cells(1, 35) Then 
        Worksheets("Purchase Log").Rows(a).Hidden = False
    Else
        Worksheets("Purchase Log").Rows(a).Hidden = True
    End If
```

For example I would like the search "cat" to also include any rows with "Bobcat" but current code can only produce "Bobcat" if text in box is exactly "Bobcat"

Comment: You can use `InStr()` to test. As an example, this will pass the `if`: `If InStr(1, "dogcatdog", "cat") Then`

Comment: `2 Or 6` is a bitwise operation evaluating to 6. Is that what you intend?

Comment: It was intended to search column 2 and 6

Comment: Try `If Worksheets("Purchase Log").Cells(a, 2).Value = Cells(1, 35) Or Worksheets("Purchase Log").Cells(a, 6).Value = Cells(1, 35)`. Alternatively, check out the `Range.AutoFilter` method.

Comment: the (a, 2 or 6) is successfully searching the 2 columns, the issue is its searching for a an exact match when all I need is a partial match.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just looking at column 6 and ignoring 2?

Comment: It is ignoring 2, thank you for that catch.

Comment: I have looked into the InStr function and i'm just not sure how to insert it into this code.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot. It uses `Like` with wildcard on front and back to capture, for example "theDog", "Dog", or "Doggie" with search term of "Dog".

```
With Worksheets("Purchase Log")

    Dim theMatch as String
    theMatch = .cells(1,35).Value

    For a = 2 to 200 

        If .Cells(a,2).Value Like "*" & theMatch & "*" Or _
            .Cells(a,6).Value Like "*" & theMatch & "*" Then
                .Rows(a).Hidden = False
        Else
            .Rows(a).Hidden = True
        End If

   Next

End With
```

Comment: Theres an error in the syntax in the If line. @Scott Holtzman